# an element of the Weyl group fixing a vector in the fundamental Weyl chamber

Tags: lie-algebras, weyl-group

I am trying to solve exercise 10.12 from humphreys lie algebra book.
I need to prove that if an element $\sigma$ of the Weyl group is such that $\sigma v=v$ for $v$ a vector in the fundamental Weyl chamber then $\sigma$ must be the identity.

My attempt was trying to prove that $\sigma $ fixes all vectors in the weyl chamber which would imply that $\sigma$ fixes a basis of $E$ an therefore is the identity. Unfortunately I couldn't prove this so I don't know what to do.

Comment: You may modify a sentence in the proof of Lemma 10.3 B to conclude: ....... Now $0\ge(\mu,\sigma\alpha)=(\sigma^{-1}\lambda,\alpha)=(\lambda,\alpha)>0$, because $\lambda\in\mathfrak C(\Delta)$. But this is already a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the following result:

> Corollary 10.2 - C (*Humphreys Intro to Lie Algebras*, pg. 50): *If $\sigma = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_t$ is a expression for $\sigma \in \mathcal{W}$ in terms of reflections corresponding to simple roots, with $t$ as small as possible, then $\sigma(\alpha_t) \prec  0$. Here, $\sigma_i = \sigma_{\alpha_i}$.*

Recall that, since $\Delta$ is a basis for $\Phi$, $\beta \in \Phi \Rightarrow \beta = \sum_{\alpha \in \Delta}k_\alpha \alpha$, for some $k_\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $\beta \prec 0$, then all $k_\alpha$ in the previous description are non positive.

Now to the problem: If $\gamma$ is in the fundamental Weyl chamber, then for every $\alpha \in \Delta$ it is true that $(\gamma, \alpha) > 0$. Since $\sigma(\gamma) = \gamma$, we have $$0 < (\gamma, \alpha) = (\sigma(\gamma), \sigma(\alpha)) = (\gamma, \sigma(\alpha)), \forall \alpha \in \Delta.$$ If $\sigma \neq 1$, one can write $\sigma$ in terms of reflections corresponding to simple roots, as follows: $$\sigma = \sigma_1 \cdots \sigma_t$$
with $t$ minimal. But, since $\alpha_t \in \Delta$, we have $0 < (\gamma, \sigma(\alpha_t))$, and by the corollary above, $\sigma(\alpha_t) = \sum_{\alpha \in \Delta}k_\alpha \alpha$ with every $k_\alpha \leq 0$. It follows that $$0 < \sum_{\alpha \in \Delta}k_\alpha (\gamma, \alpha).$$ By hypothesis, $(\gamma, \alpha) > 0$, so each term $k_\alpha (\gamma, \alpha)$ is non positive, a contradiction.

Therefore, $\sigma = 1$.

Comment: Could we also prove it by saying that the action of Weyl group on Weyl chambers is simply transitive?

Comment: @cip Yes, this seems to be the easiest way to conclude.